# Синтаксический разбор и схема предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, спп, придаточное-предложение

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить **вид придаточного** в следующем предложении:

*У Прасковьи Ивановны, как оказалось, были нервы, чего раньше как-то никто не замечал.*

Comment: Приведите свой вариант разбора, что вам непонятно?  Вопрос интересный, но в таком виде его могут закрыть (как домашнее задание).

Comment: Правка : предлагается вариант оформления вопроса, если вы в чем-то затрудняетесь.  Названа конкретная проблема (вид придаточного предложения).

Answer (score 1):

*У Прасковьи Ивановны, **как оказалось**, были нервы, **чего** раньше как-то никто не замечал.*

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным **присоединительным**. Для связи используется союзное слово ***ЧЕГО*** (оно вмещает в себя содержание первой части). Главное предложение двусоставное, осложнено **вводным** словом. Придаточное предложение двусоставное.

**Схема:** [... (в.слово)=-], (с.с.чего -=).

Подробный план разбора **[у Литневской](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p96).**